# Changing subversion local repository path after migration from Windows to macOS

Tags: macos, svn, visual-studio-code

Update:

I'm struggling with this because I'm confused about the terminology and how it maps to the actual folders. I think that, since my repository has a 'WorkingCopy' folder, that I need to do a relocate rather than checking out a new working copy.
I've simply zipped up the top level of the source base on my Windows computer, so the folder structure look like this:

```
Blah
-Repository
-WorkingCopy
 |
  -trunk
```

I extract this into the macOS Finder, where the directory structure is preserved. In the terminal, I type `SVN info | grep URL:` while in the Blah\WorkingCopy folder, and the result is:

```
URL: file:///C:/Users/Richard%20Drysdall/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202017/Projects/Blah/Repository
Relative URL: ^/
```

The best I can manage for parameters to svn relocate is

```
svn relocate "file:///C:/Users/Richard Drysdall/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/Blah/WorkingCopy/trunk" file:///Users/richard/Documents/Blah/WorkingCopy/trunk
```

but that results in the following error:

```
svn: E155024: Invalid source URL prefix: 'file:///C:/Users/Richard%20Drysdall/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202017/Projects/Blah/WorkingCopy/trunk' (does not overlap target's URL 'file:///C:/Users/Richard%20Drysdall/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202017/Projects/Blah/Repository')
```

I've played around with combinations of different folders as per the directory structure I posted above, but with no success.

Original post:

I have a local subversion repository on a Windows computer, which I have been committing to using Visual Studio and Ankh/TortoiseSVN. I intend to permanently migrate this repository to a macOS computer (still as a local repository) and use Visual Studio Code to do further development. I copied the entire repository folder to the macOS, and installed the SVN extension for Visual Studio Code. The Source Control sidebar shows changes and unversioned files, and the Subversion sidebar shows the repository, but lists the path as

`file:///<path on original windows computer>`

Attempting to commit changes results in an error:

`Commit failed (details follow): Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///<original windows path to trunk folder>' Unable to open repository 'file:///<original windows path to trunk folder>'`

If I click + at the top of the Subversion sidebar to 'Add repo-like path', I'm prompted to "Enter a SVN URL or local path..." Assuming I want the latter, I can't figure out what to enter as the local path - the topmost source folder is "~/Documents/Blah", but trying this or some sub-folders ("~/Documents/Blah/Repository" or "~/Documents/Blah/WorkingCopy") results in a message "Failed to add repo:"

How do I tell Visual Studio Code and the SVN extension where my repository is so that I can commit? Or have I done something wrong prior to this, or am I misunderstand the problem?

I'm not using a subversion client on macOS.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [checkout a new working copy](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/initial/) using a new path or [relocate existing working copy](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/relocate/) to the new local path.

The path on macOS should look like this:

```
file:///var/svn/repos/MyRepo/MyProject/trunk
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @bahrep, and apologies for my tardy acknowledgement - I have been trying to get this to work, but I'm hindered by my ignorance of the terminology and how it maps to the folder structure. I've put an update at the top of my original post that explains in more detail the issue I now have.